# Change the UIVIewController of a tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITabBarController with 4 tabs. I have a login scene in 2nd tab.When user logins I want to replace the login scene with user profile scene. From next time onwards when ever user selects 2nd tab I want to show them the user profile scene. How is this possible?

Comment: You can store a boolean value representing whether the user has logged in or not. Before loading the view controller of the specific tab, check the boolean value first, if it's yes then load the user profile view controller, if no, then load the default one.

Comment: Currently I am initializing TabViewController in the AppDelegate with viewcontrollers. Form here I can check whether the user is logged in or not and give appropriate viewcontrollers to tabview. But my problem is, inside the application when the user is not logged in, first I want to show them the login scene and after login I want to replace the login scene with profile scene. Since i am new to iOS can you please help me with some codes or detailed steps I want to follow.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

While setting up tabViewController, check if user is logged in or not. If logged in then add Profile view as the first view for the second tab.

While in application after login if you want to change the tab then, on click of second tab present a login screen over the tabView controller. And after login dismiss the login screen. If logged in then display the content of profile screen.

Comment: Currently I am initializing TabViewController in the AppDelegate with viewcontrollers. Form here I can check whether the user is logged in or not and give appropriate viewcontrollers to tabview. But my problem is, inside the application when the user is not logged in, first I want to show them the login scene and after login I want to replace the login scene with profile scene. Since i am new to iOS can you please help me with some codes or detailed steps I want to follow.

Comment: Thats what I explained in the above second paragraph. You have to initialize your Profile view controller in AppDelegate.

Now when you touch the second tab, ideally it should display Profile view. Here you have to add a condition that if not logged in then call Login scene and present it (not push). Once login completes dismiss that Login scene.

Comment: UI perspective, if not logged in the Profile view should display some text saying log-in to access profile section and place a login button on top right corner of where ever you like. By touching the login button you should present a Login scene. Or else you can automatically pop-up the login scene as soon as the profile scene is loaded.

Present a controller means:
    [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];